# Generate matrix NxN where average of row is in row and avrage of column is in column

Tags: python, matrix

I am solving some python problems and been bashing my head to solve this task. I need to generate matrix N x N filled with natural numbers where:

- Average of numbers in each row is natural number which is present in
  that row
- Average of numbers in each column is natural number which    is
  present in that column
- All numbers in matrix are different

So far I have generated matrix and tried with `random.choice` but I don't see a way to handle it so that both row and columns have average present in that row/column.

Here is my code:

```
import random
used_numbers = []
matrix = []
matrix_done = False
rows_generated = 0

n = int(input("please enter number for nxn matrix: "))
start = 1
max_n = n

while(matrix_done is False):
    row = random.sample(range(start, max_n + 1), n)
    average = sum(row) / len(row)
    print("row", row, average)
    start = max_n + 1
    max_n = max_n + n

    print("start***", start, max_n)

    matrix.append(row)

    if(average > 0 and average.is_integer()):
        print("is integer true")
        rows_generated += 1

    if(rows_generated == n):
        matrix_done = True

for row in matrix:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the code below using the following principle:

- If n is even: it is just an arithmetic progression
- If n is odd: we have to compensate the last element of each line, column and the very last of them to ensure the average is inside the matrix

I defined a the start at 10 so it makes easy to check results. But you can make it start in any given random number if you wish.

```
import random
import numpy as np

# Get user inputs
n = int(input("please enter number for nxn matrix: "))
s =  10 # First element in the matrix. Can use random.randint(1, 100)
r = 2 # Arithmetic progression ratio
c = n*(r + 1) # How much change from one line to another. Use it to avoid having the same numbers

# Now we have to scenarios: the calculation is done differently if n is iven or odd
if (n % 2 == 0):
    elements = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            e = s + r*j + c*i
            
            if j == n - 1 and i == n - 1: # Last element of the matrix
                e += c*n/2 + n
            elif j == n - 1: # last element of the line
                e += r*n/2
            elif i == n - 1: # last element of the column
                e += c*n/2
            else:
                pass
            elements.append(e)

else:
    # If the number is even, we just need to create an arithmetic progression and reshape it into a matrix
    elements = [s + r*i for i in range(n*n)]

matrix = np.reshape(elements, (n, n))
print(matrix)
```